# Programatically Get Monitor Make, Model and Serial No in CentOS

Tags: centos, monitor

I need to scan multiple Linux machines running CentOS and get the systems and monitor details - Make, Model and Serial No. The machines have Nvidia GPU installed. Commands such as dmidecode are able to get a lot of hardware info such as Model, Serial No and Proc Details, but is not able to get me the Monitor Details.

Any directions to help get the Monitor details will be highly appreciated. A google search results into a lot of info on how to get it for Ubuntu - but those methods are not working on CentOS.